# Hibernate object references an unsaved transient instance with one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two domains User and Authority. These two domains has One to Many unidirectional relationship using third table.

**User Domain:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Data
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2507177602107639240L;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable
    List<Authority> authorities;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    String username;

    boolean accountNonExpired = true;

    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;

    boolean enabled = false;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    UserDetail userDetail;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }

}
```

**Authority Domain:**

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@ToString
@Data
public class Authority extends AbstractEntity implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3506805573570762491L;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    String authority;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Authority(){}

    public Authority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public Authority(Role role) {
        this(role.toString());
    }
}
```

On the application start I persisted all the available authorities in db.

```
mysql> select * from authority;
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------------+
| id | created_by | date_created | last_updated | updated_by | authority        |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  1 | NULL       | NULL         | NULL         | NULL       | ROLE_CUSTOMER    |
|  2 | NULL       | NULL         | NULL         | NULL       | ROLE_ADMIN_READ  |
|  3 | NULL       | NULL         | NULL         | NULL       | ROLE_ADMIN_WRITE |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I am trying to save user with an authority.

```
@Transactional
private void createAdminUser(){
    String username = "admin";
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        List<Authority> authorities = authorityRepository.findAllByAuthority(Role.ROLE_ADMIN_WRITE.toString());
        user = new User(username, "admin");
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now I am getting exception like authority is not persisted.

**Error Logs:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.legacybuy.model.Authority; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.legacybuy.model.Authority
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.legacybuy.config.BootStrap.createAdminUser(BootStrap.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.legacybuy.config.BootStrap.onApplicationEvent(BootStrap.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.legacybuy.config.BootStrap.onApplicationEvent(BootStrap.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.finished(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.legacybuy.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.legacybuy.model.Authority
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1689) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(EntityManagerImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.legacybuy.model.Authority
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1313) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. See my answer below.

Comment: Can not find n-m relation in the code.

Comment: @PeterRader I think this is  
    \@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    \@JoinTable
    List<Authority> authorities;

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal Ah, ok, but its a *1-n* not a *n-m* like the title say. A correct `Many to Many` has no entity for the relation-table. This is important because some special rules are only for relation-tables like combined-unique-primary-key, not-null, only-two-fields, foregin-key-only, one-side-delete-cascade, one-side-update-cascade

Comment: @PeterRader Just updated the question.

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal Tnx

Comment: @Deepak, where are the id fields? Are they of type primitive?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee id is defined in AbstractEntity

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal, Oh! I faced the same problem.The problem was solved when I converted the id type to the respective wrapper class.  I found this after debugging  org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue.isUnsaved(Object).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your `findByAuthority` call participates in its own transaction, returning a detached / transient `Authority` instance and you're later delegating to your user's repository and it fails because `Authority` is transient.

The best way to handle this is to make sure that your transaction boundary happens earlier in the method call stack so that both repository operations occur within the same transaction context.

```
@Transactional
public void createAdminUser(String userName) {
  // your logic here
}
```

Another *hack* solution here in this case would be to alter the mapping for your `List<Authority>` property so that it cascades operations from `User` to `Authority`.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List<Authority> authorities;
```

Obviously the best approach is to make sure that all repository calls participate in the broader transaction scope so that no entity becomes detached as part of the business use case.

Comment: I had added @Transactional annototion but  it does not work.

Comment: cascade = CascadeType.ALL does not work for me as ROLE_ADMIN_WRITE already exists.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your User constructor, you are calling AuthorityUtil and it returns a list of detached authority entities.

```
public User(String username, String password, Authority authority) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = AuthorityUtil.getAsList(authority);
}
```

Make sure that method, getAsList, is not instantiating new Authority classes.

Comment: I had removed AuthorityUtil, but it still does not work me. Have a look on updated one createAdminUser() method.

Comment: In that case, I agree with @Naros. This has to do with the Authority entities being obtained in another session, i.e. detached objects. Just because you annotate the service method with Transactional, doesn't mean that you get the same session for every call, unless the session context scope is JTA. What is the scope of your session? Are you setting hibernate.current_session_context_class? Are you using JTA?